# Importing launcher3 into Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-launcher

I'm probably not understanding Gradle correctly, but when I clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/ from the website and import it into android studio, I get this error:

> Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileResolver;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

What steps should I take to get it to work? Performing the suggested resolution methods still throw this error.

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Performing the suggested resolution methods still throw this error.

Comment: @cricket_007 2.1.3